# Wordpress admin page working slow while LAN is connected

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, woocommerce, xampp

I have a WordPress 6.0.2 installation on XAMPP, using Apache and MySQL on Windows 11.
For some reason, the administrator (wp-admin) runs slow when I turn on the Internet connection in Windows...
The only thing I know is that the problem is caused by WooCommerce, because when I deactivate that plugin, the site works very fast... It's not a CPU or RAM problem, because when I open the WP-ADMIN page, I open the task manager of Windows, and resources are not being used (8GB DDR3/Intel Core i5-2400S)...

Please help... Thank you for your time

P.D: I have done several tests of the time it took to load...

- Wordpress Dashboard, internet activated, WooCommerce deactivated:
  01,53 seconds CONNECTING, around 0 seconds loading.
- Wordpress Dashboard, internet deactivated, WooCommerce deactivated:
  01,82 seconds CONNECTING, around 0 seconds loading.
- Wordpress Dashboard, internet deactivated, WooCommerce activated:
  02,68 seconds CONNECTING, around 0 seconds loading.
- Wordpress Dashboard, internet activated, WooCommerce activated: 23,02 seconds CONNECTING, around 0 seconds loading.
- RAM (HIGHEST): 4.5/8GB (XAMPP CONTROL PANEL: 464.0MB)
- RAM (LOWEST): 4.5/8GB (XAMPP CONTROL PANEL: 459.0MB)
- CPU (HIGHEST, WHEN THE SITE IS LOADING): 80%
- CPU (LOWEST, WHEN THE SITE IS LOADING): 77%
- CPU (WHEN THE SITE FINISHED LOADING): 10%

Comment: Internet connection ON/OFF slows down things because of HTTP calls, it could be an API call for a Theme/Plugin/Core version update, CDN urls, Extenrmal images, or scripts. WooCommerce brings so many things on When you activate it so CPU & RAM will go high for sure. You can install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) If you want to debug and see what queries and HTTP calls you're making.

Comment: @VijayHardaha and there is a method to disable internet for a specific plugin?

Comment: @Martín What is your tolerance for having WooCommerce disabled?  Minutes ?  Do you have a published maintenance scheduled downtime for your customers?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have various days to get this to work

Comment: With your internet connection OFF, A) from OS Command Prompt   netstat  -e -s >netstat-off-begin.txt  then wait 5 minutes, B) netstat -e -s >netstat-off-end.txt  turn ON internet connection.  C) netstat -e -s >netstat-on-begin.txt   NOW use your WooCommerce involved application for 5 minutes in some way.  D) netstat -e -s >netstat-on-end.txt  and post all 4 output text files for analysis, please.